# winapi c - any simple method for adding an image?

Tags: c, winapi, window

I am new to plain winapi c and was wondering if there is any simple method for adding an image to my GUI, if possible I would like this image to essentially part of the code so that I only have to send the single executable file when sending others the GUI.

EDIT:

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HBITMAP g_hbmBall = NULL;
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
  MSG  msg;    
  HWND hwnd;
  WNDCLASSW wc;

  wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
  wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
  wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
  wc.lpszClassName = L"Window";
  wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
  wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
  wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
  wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
  wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

  RegisterClassW(&wc);
  hwnd = CreateWindowW( wc.lpszClassName, L"Window",
                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                100, 100, 350, 250, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);  

  ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
  UpdateWindow(hwnd);

  while( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }

  return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, 
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch(msg)  
  {
    case WM_CREATE:
            g_hbmBall = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BALL));
            if(g_hbmBall == NULL)
                MessageBox(hwnd, "Could not load IDB_BALL!", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        break;

case WM_PAINT:
        {
            BITMAP bm;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;

            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, g_hbmBall);

            GetObject(g_hbmBall, sizeof(bm), &bm);

            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);
            DeleteDC(hdcMem);

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:

      PostQuitMessage(0);
      DeleteObject(g_hbmBall);
      return 0;      
  }

  return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image should be a `bitmap`, you should make it a resource with your `resource editor` and use [LoadBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [LoadImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to load it in your `exe`. Use [BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , [StretchBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [TransparentBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to draw it ( use last two if you want to shrink/enlarge it to fit your window-`TransparentBlt` also makes parts of your image transparent-see documentation ). Do not forget to delete the resource when you are done-usually in your `WM_CLOSE` handler with `DeleteObject` API.

### EDIT:

---

As *Remy Lebeau* said, you can use workaround by putting a static control on your window and set it to display image. I do not know what suits you better since your post is scarse on information. I still suggest to use `GDI` to draw a picture since you can try to use all kind of *stretching modes* to improve images quality.

---

[This](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/) tutorial has some examples, and is good in general for learning the `Win32 API`.

Good luck.

Best regards.

Comment: I have added the image as a resource to my IDE (test1.rc) but am having problems understanding how to add it to my code, could you please show me as an example on the simple window code attached above? I greatly appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: @RahulKhosla: Just go through the tutorial provided in my answer-[here](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/bitmaps.html) is the link to the example. It shows how to load resource and how to display it. **Download the source code and PDF** from the tutorials link. Source code will show you how exactly to do what you need. If you need further help leave another comment and I will help. Best regards.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that there was so many useful examples available for free! I have tried to modify my code please see edit above, I keep getting an error saying  error #2048: Undeclared identifier 'IDB_BALL', from what I understand this is supposed to be the name of the rc which I have imported and called but I keep getting this error, could you please help me with this.

Comment: @RahulKhosla: `g_hbmBall = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BALL));`->change to this `g_hbmBall = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_YOURIMAGE));`. You just have to pass the ID of your image-look up in your resource file how it is stored. In `Visual Studio` open `.rc` file and see the ID of your picture, it should be something like `IDB_SOMETHING`. Than pass it as the last parameter the way I showed you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the image data to your executable's resources at compile-time via an `.rc` file, then load the image at runtime via [`LoadImage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  If you put a [`STATIC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control on your UI, you can send it an [`STM_SETIMAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760782%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to display the image.